# How to deploy Jenkins builds into a Maven repository on the local filesystem

Tags: java, maven, build, hudson, jenkins

I want to store builds in my own directory and I don't want to run Sonatype Nexus or similar. Is this possible?

I set up Jenkins to deploy artifact into my Maven repository and filled in this URL

```
file:///home/tomas/.m2/repository
```

If I try to build the project, I will get this exception

```
Maven RedeployPublished use remote  maven settings from : /var/lib/jenkins/tools/mvn/conf/settings.xml
[INFO] Deployment in /home/tomas/.m2/repository (id=,uniqueVersion=true)
Deploying the main artifact wst-root-pom-1.0.pom
ERROR: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository  (/home/tomas/.m2/repository) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.ArtifactDeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository  (/home/tomas/.m2/repository) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:141)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.MavenArtifactRecord.deploy(MavenArtifactRecord.java:182)
    at hudson.maven.RedeployPublisher.perform(RedeployPublisher.java:176)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:19)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.perform(AbstractBuild.java:703)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:678)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$RunnerImpl.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:998)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.post(AbstractBuild.java:625)
    at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1435)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:481)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:238)
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.deployment.DeploymentException: Failed to deploy artifacts/metadata: No connector available to access repository  (/home/tomas/.m2/repository) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:235)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:211)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRepositorySystem.deploy(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:443)
    at org.apache.maven.artifact.deployer.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:137)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.sonatype.aether.transfer.NoRepositoryConnectorException: No connector available to access repository  (/home/tomas/.m2/repository) of type default using the available factories WagonRepositoryConnectorFactory
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.getRepositoryConnector(DefaultRemoteRepositoryManager.java:400)
    at org.sonatype.aether.impl.internal.DefaultDeployer.deploy(DefaultDeployer.java:231)
    ... 14 more
[INFO] Deployment failed after 0,26 sec
Build step 'Deploy artifacts to Maven repository' changed build result to FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3):

I recall that is a maven 3 compatibility problem. According to the notes: https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-TransportProtocols%2528Wagons%2529

> Unlike Maven 2, Maven 3 supports out of the box only http:, https: and
>   file: as transport protocols. To use other transport protocols like
>   scp:, the appropriate wagons have to be explicitly declared in the POM
>   as a build extension. If the wagon in question is only used for
>   deployment to a repository, it can alternatively be declared as a
>   dependency of the Maven Deploy Plugin.

So make sure you are using Maven 3, otherwise you have to download your own wagon as an maven extension. Here is a guide to using Maven extensions:
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-extensions.html

**Note:** Wagon 1.0-beta-3+ requires Maven 2.1.0 or above. For Maven 2.0.10 and earlier, use Wagon 1.0-beta-2.

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <extensions>
      <extension>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
         <artifactId>wagon-file</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-beta-3</version>
      </extension>
    </extensions>
  </build>
  ...
</project>
```

That should resolve your issue. If it doesn't work, double check your maven path to see if different versions don't conflict.

Comment: Well this should, but does not for me either. It seems that the "Deploy Maven Artifcats" Post Build Step of Jenkins does not honor this extension.